# how to transfer the selected itinerary details to revalidation or PNR creation?

Tags: php, sabre

Im using sabre rest api. i have done my code up-to searching fare via BagainFinderMax (v1.8.6) and I'm still confusing what is next? either doing the 
Revalidate Itinerary or Create Passenger Name Record. how can i pick the specific itinerary via workflow to do above process in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend on what you want to accomplish. Bear in mind that CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ won't work with complex itineraries that require an ARNK segment for instance. Roughly, you could look for options in BFM and then call Revalidate (a pre-booking step). Once you validate that you can book the itinerary with EnhancedAirBookRQ and proceed to the final ticketing step.

Comment: thank you for help. I'm now working on Revalidation via BFM. i have some issue. my revalidation request is as follow.

Comment: thank for your reply. ya I'm working on Revalidation now.